# How Generational Garbage Collection works?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How Generational GC works ?
Totally what is Generational GC ?

thanks

Comment: What do you want to know that the wikipedia page doesn't cover?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Generational_GC_.28ephemeral_GC.29

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+Generational+GC+works 21,600,000 hits

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I got 2,770,000 hits! How did you get huge results? *sarcastic laugh*

Comment: ?? "About 21,600,000 results (0.06 seconds) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia's explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Generational_GC_.28ephemeral_GC.29).

> A generational GC (also known as
>   ephemeral GC) divides objects into
>   generations and, on most cycles, will
>   place only the objects of a subset of
>   generations into the initial white
>   (condemned) set. Furthermore, the
>   runtime system maintains knowledge of
>   when references cross generations by
>   observing the creation and overwriting
>   of references. When the garbage
>   collector runs, it may be able to use
>   this knowledge to prove that some
>   objects in the initial white set are
>   unreachable without having to traverse
>   the entire reference tree. If the
>   generational hypothesis holds, this
>   results in much faster collection
>   cycles while still reclaiming most
>   unreachable objects.

Basically, it's a heuristic approach. The Garbage collection puts newly created objects in a memory region (called *white set*), when this set is full, those objects that are still referenced are moved to another region, and the white set is cleared and populated with fresh new objects. The white set is the hypothesis that the objects found there are generally unreachable.

For further reading on JVM Fine-Tuning of [Garbage Collection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#1.1.%20Generations%7Coutline).

Answer (score 3):

Simply, a generational collector manages memory in a series of areas of increasingly longer-lived objects. These areas are called *generations*. The youngest generation -- sometimes called the *Eden generation* -- consists of objects that have just been created. It tends to see a *lot* of change -- objects come and go from this generation all the time. The older generations have a lot less change. That's because the longer an object lasts, the more likely it is to continue to last.

A generational collector gains efficiency by partitioning memory this way, because it can spend most of its time looking in the small Eden generation, and it can ignore the oldest generations most of the time. By limiting the amount of memory that needs looking at, the collector reduced the amount of work it needs to do.