# Generational Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

As I understand, a generational GC divides objects into generations.
And on each cycle, GC runs on only one generation.

Why? Why Garbage Collecting of only one generation is enough?

P.S: I understand all these from  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Generational_GC_.28ephemeral_GC.29) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#1.1.%20Generations%7Coutline) I provided in [earlier question you had about Generational GC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489773/how-generational-garbage-collection-works), you will understand why it does so, the cycle is when the *white set* memory is filled up.

> To optimize for this scenario, memory
>   is managed in generations, or memory
>   pools holding objects of different
>   ages. Garbage collection occurs in
>   each generation when the generation
>   fills up. Objects are allocated in a
>   generation for younger objects or the
>   young generation, and because of
>   infant mortality most objects die
>   there. When the young generation fills
>   up it causes a minor collection. Minor
>   collections can be optimized assuming
>   a high infant mortality rate. The
>   costs of such collections are, to the
>   first order, proportional to the
>   number of live objects being
>   collected. A young generation full of
>   dead objects is collected very
>   quickly. Some surviving objects are
>   moved to a tenured generation. When
>   the tenured generation needs to be
>   collected there is a major collection
>   that is often much slower because it
>   involves all live objects.

Basically, each objects is divided into generations (based on the hypothesis about the object) and places them into a memory heap for a particular generation. When that memory heap is filled up, the GC cycle begins, and those objects that still references are moved to another memory heap and fresh objects are added.

Comment: **Garbage collection occurs in each generation when the generation fills up.** I can't understand, how GC can occur in only one generation? GC uses Tri-color making algorithm, no? Tri-color making algorithm can't done on only one generation, it needs whole objects.

Comment: @Hessam, for Generative GC, when the white set memory is filled (don't forget there are more than 1 white set), GC kicks in for that white set. Each white set contains a specific generate based on the heuristic of the GC. Tri-colour marking is just a strategy for GC, there are also mark-and-sweep (which Java and .NET uses) but these are strategies to reclaim memory.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, how GC runs on only one generation? There are some objects in a generation which are pointed at from outside. How GC can handle this? As you said, GC occur in only one generation (white set) how GC knows which objects in this generation are pointed at from outside?

Comment: @Hessam, Wikipedia clearly explains this. While the JVM runs, it gets knowledge on how the object is used. "`Furthermore, the runtime system maintains knowledge of when references cross generations by observing the creation and overwriting of references. When the garbage collector runs, it may be able to use this knowledge to prove that some objects in the initial white set are unreachable without having to traverse the entire reference tree. If the generational hypothesis holds, this results in much faster collection cycles while still reclaiming most unreachable objects.`".

Comment: Please refer to your previous question, I answered it **exactly** there.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, oops! thanks, actually this is because of my terrible English. But finally I got my answer, thanks man ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's not *always* enough -- it's just that it's *usually* enough, so it saves time by not examining objects that are likely to stay alive anyway.

Every object has a generation, saying how many garbage collections it has survived. If an object has survived a few garbage collections, chances are that it will also survive the next one.

[MSDN has a great explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx):

> A generational garbage collector makes the following assumptions:
>
> - The newer an object is, the shorter its lifetime will be.
> - The older an object is, the longer its lifetime will be.
> - Newer objects tend to have strong relationships to each other and are frequently accessed around the same time.
> - Compacting a portion of the heap is faster than compacting the whole heap.

Because of this, you could save some time by only trying to collect younger objects, and collecting the older generations only if that doesn't free up enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is there really.

> It has been empirically observed that in many programs, the most recently created objects are also those most likely to become unreachable quickly (known as infant mortality or the generational hypothesis).

And

> Generational garbage collection is a heuristic approach, and some unreachable objects may not be reclaimed on each cycle. It may therefore occasionally be necessary to perform a full mark and sweep or copying garbage collection to reclaim all available space.

Basically, generational collection gives you better performance over a full garbage collection at the cost of completeness. That's why a mixture of the two is used in practice.