# What if an object in the old generation need to reference an object in the young generation?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Lets say there is an object in the old generation which need a reference to an object which is in the  young generation. `Now when a GC is executed for the young generation, what will happen to that object which is referenced by the object in old generation? Will it continue to be in young generation or moved to young generation or GCed?`

Also there is this card table which decided the objects for minor GC. `How does it work in the above context?`

Comment: From what I understand GC doesn't recursively check all references of an object it collects. This means the object in the old generation will be removed when the GC for that generation is executed. It will also stay in that generation until than as an object can only move upwards in the generations.

Comment: Well it can't be GC'd, can it, not if it's still referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each object, the GC keeps track of how many GC cycles it went through. the decision of 'promoting' an object to a different pool is a per object decision.
an object will not be garbage collected if there are live references to it which are rooted (not circular dependency).
this decision is made after the objects of a particular pool have been evaluated for collection (GC ran on their pool). in other words, if that object have a live reference it will not be collected. any objects without a live reference will be collected regardless of which pool hey exist in. the pools are really a matter of GC optimization: to make the GC as quick as possible, objects in older pool (Survivors, Permgen etc) are not evaluated as frequently as objects in younger generations.

Answer (score 1):

See [Generational Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491682/generational-garbage-collection): "Furthermore, the runtime system maintains knowledge of when references cross generations by observing the creation and overwriting of references. When the garbage collector runs, it may be able to use this knowledge to prove that some objects in the initial white set are unreachable without having to traverse the entire reference tree. If the generational hypothesis holds, this results in much faster collection cycles while still reclaiming most unreachable objects."

So to answer your question, it will stay alive and promoted from space to space as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the way GC's work with generations. When we say young or old generation, then the primary basis of an object belonging to either one of them depends on their life span and not which references to each other.

So to answer your question then `No`. It will remain in young (or might be moved to older) depending on when it was initialized. `Referencing` is used (for ex in Mark and Sweep) to see if an object is strongly reachable and not to decide the generation.

And per se if you think by your logic, then all the local variables or objects even with with short life should directly be placed in older generation just because an object from old generation references all of them :). Luckily it doesn't that way.

Comment: I don't see any such misunderstanding in the question. But even assuming there is, you didn't answer the question: What happens to a young object which is (only) referenced by an old object during a minor GC.

Comment: @delnan As I said, it is independent of which object of what generation referenced it. So we cannot say definitely what will happen to it.

Comment: For starters, is it freed or kept alive? (The issue of whether it's promoted to old or stays young is indeed independent of which generation(s) it's referenced from, but that doesn't mean it can't be answered.)

Comment: yes absolutely it is alive. If an object is freed then it will not exist in any generation. here because it is referred hence it is alive